# Blazor drag and drop event preventDefault() does not exist

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, blazor

I am writing code to move some blocks around a grid using drag and drop. This is the block element:

```
                    <div class="col-span-@b.ColSpan row-span-@b.RowSpan relative border border-black box-border"
             style="order:@b.Placement[_pageType].Order;"
             @ondblclick="(() => ChangeBlockProperties(b))"
             @ondragstart="@(() => DragStart(b))"
             @ondragover="@((DragEventArgs e) => DragOver(e))"
             @ondrop="@((DragEventArgs e) => Drop(e, b))">
```

And this is the code I have written for it:

```
    private async Task DragStart(FlyerBlock block)
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("startDrag", block);
    }

    private async Task DragOver(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.PreventDefault();
    }

    private async Task Drop(DragEventArgs e, FlyerBlock targetBlock)
    {
        e.PreventDefault();
        var data = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("getDraggedBlock");
        var sourceBlock = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FlyerBlock>(data);

        // Swap the targetBlock and sourceBlock's placement
        var tempOrder = targetBlock.Placement[_pageType].Order;
        targetBlock.Placement[_pageType].Order = sourceBlock.Placement[_pageType].Order;
        sourceBlock.Placement[_pageType].Order = tempOrder;

        // Save the changes to the database
        await BlockManager.UpdateBlock(targetBlock);
        
    }
```

Both in dragover and Drop my `e.PreventDefault();` is giving me the following error: "DragEventArgs does not contain a definition for 'PreventDefault'. I am pretty sure this should be working I can't figure out why it would be giving me an error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"And this is the js code I have written"* - That's not JavaScript, that's C#.

Comment: Unless something very special is happening in your js code, you don't need ANY js code to handle drag / drop events.  In fact, it's easier to do in Blazor.

Comment: apologies I was thinking for the IJS runtime while writing this.

Comment: @Adil15: Given that update... What exactly is the issue at this point?  You're trying to call a method that doesn't exist, so remove the line that tries to call it.  From there, what problem are you trying to solve?  What doesn't work as expected that you were trying to solve by calling that method?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the preventEvent from Blazor like so

```
@ondragover:preventDefault="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out how to fix it because David gave me a hint about calling a method that didn't exist. I replaced `e.PreventDefault();` with `await js.InvokeVoidAsync("preventDefault", e);` and just used my jsruntime. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be that pretty, but you can just add a js event without any jsinterop:

```
<div @ondblclick="..."
     @ondragstart="..."
     ondragover="event.preventDefault()"
     @ondrop="...">
```